# Sort multiple arrays based on an ID array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, indexing

What i've got so far is basically 2 seperately built arrays with contents like these:

**Arraygroup #1:**

```
var nickName = ['Noah', 'Liam', 'Jacob', 'Mason', 'William',];
var lastLogin = ['03042015', '02042015', '02042015', '05032015', '16022015'];
var id = [0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005];
```

**Arraygroup #2:**

```
var banStatus= [0, 0, 2, 1, 0];
var status = ['Online', 'Busy', 'Snooze', 'Offline', 'Offline'];
var id = [0003, 0005, 0001, 0004, 0002];
```

What i want to do is sort them based on the "id" array they both got, ( but sadly they are in the wrong order ).

The result should be something like this:

```
id[0] == 0001
nickName[0] == Noah
lastLogin[0] == 03042015
isBanned[0] = 2
status[0] = Snooze
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a List with two-element tuples. First element: the Id array, second element: integers 0 .. length of your array.

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> arraySortHelperList = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
for(...)
{
     int id = ...
     arraySortHelperList.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(id, n++));
}
```

Sort this list based on the Id element.

Now the second elemnt are the *sorted indices* i.e. the first item in the sorted list will contain in its second element the index of the array slot which comes first.

Answer (score 2):

Quite another answer:

Define a class which contains all the properties from your arrays:

```
class MyClass
{
     int Id;
     string nickName;
     ...
}
```

Populate a List with such objects form your arrays. Sort this list.